# Rigorous proof of cauchy's theorem in the presence of removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this question from ahlfors page149:" there is no longer any need to give a separate proof of Theorem 15 in the presence of removable singularities. "

> **Theorem 15:** *If $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Omega$, then $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$  for every cycle $\gamma$ which is homologous to zero in $\Omega$.*

If there is removable singularities in $\Omega$. I wonder how to prove the theorem rigorously.

Here is my attempt.

we only need to prove it when there is one removable singularity.
Suppose $a\in \Omega $  is a removable singularity, which means $$\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z)=0$$
then $f(z)$ is analytic in the region $\Omega^{'}=\Omega -\{a\}$, then there exists a analytic function $g(z)$ in $\Omega$ which coincides with $f(z)$ in $\Omega'$.

Then apply theorem 15 to $g(z)$, the integral can be written as $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz =\int_\gamma g(z)dz = 0 $$

Is this proof valid? Or how to give a rigorous proof?

Comment: Where did you explicitly use the fact that $a$ was removable? In concluding that such a $g$ exists?

Comment: Yes, if $a$ is removable, then we can define the value $f(a)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(z)dz}{z-a}$,where $C$ refers to a circle about $a$ and its inside are contained in$ \Omega$ @DerekAllums

Comment: Did you mean Cau**c**hy's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The proof looks correct. It would be worth to simply describe it as follows:
"After we remove the singularity, $f$ becomes analytic, so theorem 15 holds for $f$."

Comment: Thanks for the advice!